# How do I insert an HTML Script embed into React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get an eCommerce html script embed to work in React, by having it render from a component.
An example below:

```
<div data-embed="store">
    <script type="application/json">
        {"some json text"}
    </script>
</div>
<script async src="https://website.com/loader.js"></script>
```

From what I have been able to gather, I can use the useEffect hook, but have not been able to get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `useEffect` by creating a `script` element, adding the `src` and `async` attribute and appening it to the document body. You would then have the imported JS available globally.
**EDIT:**
The same can be applied to JSON with exception of having to load it in manually.

```js
const [json, setJson] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');

  script.src = "https://website.com/loader.js";
  script.async = true;

  document.body.appendChild(script);

  // json
  const jsonScript = document.createElement('script');
  jsonScript.innerHTML = `
      {
        "greeting": "hello"
      }
    `;
  jsonScript.id = 'json';
  jsonScript.type = 'application/json';

  document.body.appendChild(jsonScript);

  setJson(JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json').innerHTML));
}, []);
```

Comment: This makes sense, I guess how would I get the script tag thats wrapped in the div to use said inline JSON object?

Comment: JSON is not loaded in the same way as JS so you would have to do a bit extra work. This involves getting and parsing the `innerHTML` and setting it to its own state. I have edited the answer with an example of this.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am just trying to understand it all. I also have put the code in and placed the innterHTML and the src. I guess the question is, do I create a div with a classname/id for thios script to render?